# Prolog arguments are not sufficiently instantiated (function which calculates list length)

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I made a function which calculates a list length. Below is my code.

```
listLength(LIST) :- solve(LIST, LENGTH), write(LENGTH).
solve([], _).
solve([_|T], LENGTH) :- ADD is LENGTH + 1, solve(T, ADD).
```

When I run this code with input

> ?- listLength([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]).

then, interpreter showed me error message `solve/2 : Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.`

when I modified above code like below.

```
listLength(LIST) :- LENGTH is 0, solve(LIST, LENGTH), write(LENGTH).
solve([], _).
solve([_|T], LENGTH) :- ADD is LENGTH + 1, solve(T, ADD).
```

When I run this code with the same input, then always **0** is written.

**I want to calculate LENGTH, and I want to use the variable in listLength function.**

What's wrong with me? ( Please kindly note that I am using swi-prolog. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first mistake is in the base case. Instead of `solve([], _).` you should write `solve([], 0).` because if you don't know the length of empty list how will you find recursively for bigger lists.

There is also another issue in :

```
solve([_|T], LENGTH) :- ADD is LENGTH + 1, solve(T, ADD).
```

when trying to calculate  ADD is LENGTH + 1 length is not instantiated-calculated. You need to change the order like:

```
listLength(LIST) :- solve(LIST, LENGTH), write(LENGTH).
solve([], 0).
solve([_|T], LENGTH) :- solve(T, ADD), LENGTH  is ADD+ 1.
```

Now querying:

```
?- listLength([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]).
7
true.
```

Comment: This is very slow for queries like `listLength(L, 10000)`

Comment: How could you query that since it only takes one parameter-list??

Comment: You are right! I only saw the addition at the end. Should read `solve(L, 100000` bu t I admit, that will not happen.